# How to combine two regex for address form validation?

Tags: java, regex, validation, input, street-address

I have two regexes

1.) For invalidating PO Box:

`^(?!.*\b[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\b).*$`

2.) For invalidating special characters:

`[^x21-x7E][^x20-x7E]*$`

How can I combine these two that it invalidates PO Box in address form as well as disallow special characters? I tried different things with no luck. I also tried `@Pattern.List` and added both regex but it doesn't work. `@Pattern.List()` always invalidates all my inputs. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add some examples of expected valid and invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of using more regex in one pattern.
But in your code, i think there is a problem because of your both regex ends with `"$"`.

```
String regex1="(\\d)";  // Any Single Digit 1
String regex2="(\\d)";  // Any Single Digit 2

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
if (m.find())
{
   //jobs ...
}
```